# What is muations in google cloud spanner?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-spanner

I'm new to Google cloud Spanner, please help What is Mutation class.
How mutation works? Please give me explanation because below link dosen't explained it properly [https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/spanner/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/spanner/v1/model/Mutation.html]

Comment: I would reccomend running through the tutorials at https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/  and the Java client library javadoc https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-spanner/1.6.0/index.html?com/google/cloud/spanner/Mutation.html to get an idea of the APIs and classes used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#write-data-with-mutations):

> A mutation represents a sequence of inserts, updates, and deletes that Cloud Spanner applies atomically to different rows and tables in a Cloud Spanner database.

You can also see in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/modify-mutation-api) how to insert, update, and delete data using mutations, in order to know how it works.